# akka typed actors, how to expose / share child actor's actoref

Tags: scala, akka, akka-actor

Using akka-actor-typed 2.8.x, how does one gain access to spawned child actor's actorRef?

I have a guardian actor that spawns a child actor and registers it with receptionist. Then in my route traits I use the receptionist.find to locate the actor and use it which then gives me a future[actorref]. I'd prefer to either pass the child actorRef as a parameter or expose in trait mixin but am unsure how to do this.

ActorSytem is created with guardian actor which then in turn spawns the child actor (RedisActor).

guardian and ActorSystem

```
  val guardian: Behavior[NotUsed] = Behaviors.setup { context =>
    val redisActor = context.spawn(RedisActor(redisUrl), "redis-actor")
    context.system.receptionist ! Receptionist.Register(RedisActor.RedisActorServiceKey, redisActor)
    Behaviors.empty
  }

  implicit val system: ActorSystem[NotUsed] = ActorSystem[NotUsed](guardian, "AdminHttpServer")
```

and lastly, RedisActor:

```
object RedisActor {
  def apply1(redisUrl: String): Behavior[RedisCommands] =
    Behaviors.setup(context => new RedisActor(context, redisUrl))

  def apply(redisUrl: String): Behavior[RedisCommands] =
    Behaviors.supervise(Behaviors.setup[RedisCommands](context => new RedisActor(context, redisUrl)))
      .onFailure(SupervisorStrategy.restart) //TODO look at wait time
   ...
}
class RedisActor(context: ActorContext[RedisCommands], redisUrl: String) extends AbstractBehavior[RedisActor.RedisCommands](context) {
   ...
}
```

Challenge, here is that `redisActor` is 'hidden' within guardian function and I would like to get access to it without having to use receptionist. Is there a different way to spawn the child, something like:

```
val redisActor = system....spawn(RedisActor(redisUrl), "redis-actor")
```

There must be as docs hint at multiple ways but I am not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward approach would be to define a message type that the guardian could reply to with an ActorRef to its child.

The docs for creating actors have a direct example of this: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/actor-lifecycle.html#spawning-children where the parent creates a child and returns it in response to a `SayHello` message. The only difference between your scenario and the scenario of the example is that you are creating the child in the guardian's setup and the example spawns a child per message received.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Maybe I missing some salient point (I am progressing from classic to typed) as I had seen this example and I couldn't see where is solves my problem. On receiving the sayhello message it spawns a new child actor and sends it a message.

My challenge is on how to discover the child actor without using receptionist or preferably not using an ask either (as it returns a future - but not the end of the world.

Comment: In general, in typed the only ways to get an actorref involve either spawning it or some sort of exchange of messages (e.g. the `SpawnProtocol`, the receptionist, etc.).  There is support, intended for libraries where the implementers don't have the ability to assume a particular guardian behavior, via `systemActorOf`, which would be similar to your `system.spawn` (and which would likely be accessible via an extension).

Comment: It would be most idiomatic in Typed, though, to have almost no code outside of the guardian actor's behavior: `main` sets up the guardian and the guardian sets up everything else, passing actorrefs that different bits of functionality depend on directly to those bits of functionality (`ActorRef`: the ultimate dependency injection...)

Comment: @Levi 1000% I struggled to answer this Q because I was struggling how to describe idiomatic typed Akka. But I figured it was better to try and start an answer. Feel free to edit and improve my initial response, because this is very conceptual.

Comment: @colinbes This is a vast generalization, but discovery is usually a crutch. In Akka, especially typed Akka, you should find your ActorRefs though relationships. And it shouldn't require synchronous behavior (i.e. asks) in an Actor client. ActorRefs are meant to be passed via messages, so clients should obtain and react to ActorRefs via messages.

Comment: Thanks. Currently I have a actor managing Redis calls and in the past I could simply pass the redisActor ActorRef to my router where is could send tells/asks as required to the redis actor.

Now I have to use a receptionist find to locate the actorRef and deal with another level of Futures in my Akk-Http Routes - not impossible by any means.

I know I could combine my routes and bind the HttpServer within the behavior but honestly, my mind flips out over this and doesn't feel right. Thanks for all the responses.